# A high school level proof that $a/b > 0$

Tags: proofs

Is there a high school level proof of the following?

If $a,b > 0$ then $a/b > 0.$

Comment: Hi, could you be more explicit about the connection to teaching mathematics and what you know already?

Comment: Technically, if you start with the axioms of ordered field, you can immediately get it from the identity $(a/b)b=a$ arguing that two other possible cases $a/b=0$ and $a/b<0$ lead to a contradiction. You do not need to say the scary fancy words "field" and "axiom" here, but you still need to postulate *something* to be able to derive the statement unless you want to get mired in the intricacies of the formal construction of the real field from positive integers, which I certainly would not recommend at the high school level.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the answer to this question is "yes", but this question is not about math education.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose to the contrary that $\frac ab$ were negative. Then $b \cdot \frac ab$ would be the product of a positive and a negative number, which would be negative.  But we know that $b \cdot \frac ab = a$, which is positive, so this can't be right.  Similarly, if $\frac ab$ were zero, then $b \cdot \frac ab = a$ would have to be zero as well, which isn't true.  So the only possibility left is that $\frac ab > 0$.

Comment: This looks perfect to me.

Answer (score 1):

If $b>0$, then $\frac{1}{b}>0$. Product of two positives is positive.

Comment: If $b>0$, then $\frac{1}{b}>0$. Why is that?